# When did lecherousness, in Western Culture, become a primarily male quality, instead of a female one? Or is that not true?

Tags: cultural-history, gender, western-civilisation

When did lecherousness, in Western Culture, become a primarily male quality, instead of a female one?

According to TvTropes:

[I'm a Man, I Can't Help It:](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ImAManICantHelpIt)

> Very much Newer Than They Think. In ancient times (Rome, Greece, etc.) being lecherous was considered a distinctively female characteristic; All Women Are Lustful in those settings. For a man to be described as a slave to his urges was a major insult to his masculinity.

[All Women Are Lustful:](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AllWomenAreLustful)

> This is a Cyclic Trope, having been popular historically, especially in ancient Greece. Back then, this trope actually replaced All Men Are Perverts: it was assumed that women were too sex-crazed to say no to sex, while men were supposed to hold back for the sake of propriety; being too sexual with women was an insult to a man's virility. Although mostly a Forgotten Trope and/or Discredited Trope today, this trope made a comeback in the early eighties in which beautiful sexually adventurous women are the ones who pick up guys and initiate sexual encounters.

Or... is TvTropes wrong? And I should do more research?

Comment: TVTropes describes the essence of a trope, but actual works would adapt them to their purposes. Also I feel like this is a cyclical thing with the two tropes being in fashion (mostly) alternating periodically, as well as dependant on the work/genre.

Comment: @Semaphore - Quite sure you weren't the downvote... but even if you were... (that sounds weird...) could you enlighten me on what the downvote may have been about?

Comment: Based on the close vote I'd speculate someone thinks this isn't on topic for history.SE. I'm personally on the fence, though I wouldn't think it necessary to downvote even if off-topic.

Comment: I am voting to close because I think this is too broad - this is no single Western culture. I suggest either radically editing and/or researching and asking one or more much more specific questions.

Comment: @andy256 I beg to differ - there is no single "Western" culture indeed, but the Western civilization (no matter how dubious its meaning) has a commonality in genealogy, in which it traces their development in history from Greek and Roman period to medieval and Renaissance. Though the concept of "Western" culture can be debated over and over again, the admittance of a common genealogical descent is there. Foucault discusses this in his History of Sexuality. That might be interesting for Malandy.

Comment: I do think this is a cyclic phenomenon, but maybe one with a faster frequency than you are thinking.  Did the late-Roman Stoicism of Marcus Aurelius or the praising of chastity and virginity by Paul of Tarsus become popular in Rome as a reaction to the sexualized centuries around Ovid or Caligula?  Did Puritanism rise as a syphilis-spurred reaction to Renaissance brothels?  Did Victorian sexual mores rise as a similar reaction to the sexual libertines of the 17th and 18th centuries? Did the sexual freedom of the 1960's and 1970's result from pushing back against the tail end of Victorianism?

Comment: There's a real Madonna/whore tension in some traditional views of women's sexuality. Often, the cultural emphasis on purity and chastity was due to the fear that women were naturally weak and lustful. It's like the old saw that a law against X is proof that people wanted to do X. Also, wiki on [Cult of True Womanhood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cult_of_Domesticity_)

Comment: Leprechauns have always been male. There are no female leprechauns.

Comment: @TylerDurden yeah right. And satyrs too

Comment: Simply too complicated to answer.  Powerful people of either gender have always been accused of sexual aberrancy.  If we were to study the issue clearly and fairly we'd have to look at all accusations against powerful people, group them into sexual and non-sexual, gendered and non gendered, and probably personal/professional. I'm not aware of anyone doing that (I think Hillary Mantel may have started, but I haven't read her work; I would suggest starting with her.)